# Difference between sqlsrv_fetch_array and sqlsrv_fetch_object

Tags: php, sql-server, json

Im working with PHP and MS SQL Server 2005 and 2012 , my question is what is the Difference between sqlsrv_fetch_array and sqlsrv_fetch_object?

Comment: You seem to have 3 questions in one here. What is the difference between `sqlsrv_fetch_array` and `sqlsrv_fetch_object`, which is better and why doesn't this code work in MS SQL 2005. The first two questions aren't good questions for SO. For the first, go read the manual. For the second, we don't like subject questions. For the third you probably need to try and figure it out yourself first, and then let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

**[sqlsrv_fetch_object](http://php.net/sqlsrv_fetch_object)**

> Returns an **object** on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs or if the specified class does not exist.

**[sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)**

> Returns an **array** on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs.

So the only difference is one returns an array and other returns an object.

**Which one is better?**

Neither, its your subjective preference which one to use. It also depends upon your own implementation. Both get the job done.

> This code worked good in MS SQL 2012 but doesn't in MS SQL 2005. any Suggestions, thanks

Error messages can tell more than we can.